# Specific issue aligning content dynamically using pure bootstrap 4.1.3?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Building this site where I have a main video on top, the video should be centered and taking up 7 columns on desktop and off to the right in 2 columns 3 ads stacked vertically. On mobile the same video is 12 columns and the 3 ads 3 columns each side by side. I'm almost certain this can be achieved by using `.offset` which the bootstrap documentation seems to suggest but I am not getting the desired results. Instead, what I get is the image ads stacked vertically underneath the video, this happens only in desktop and mobile portrait mode. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="mainVideoJumbotron">
            <div class="container-fluid" id="mainVideoContainer">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">

                    <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

                        <h1 class="heading text-center">I, Pet Goat &#8545;</h1>
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6n_xCI-peq0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        </div>


                    </div>


                    <div class="col-lg-2 offset-lg-10 col-md-3 col-sm-3 offset-md-0 offset-sm-0">
                        <img src="images/ads.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="ad1">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-2 offset-lg-10 col-md-3 col-sm-3 offset-md-0 offset-sm-0">
                        <img src="images/ads.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="ad2">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-2 offset-lg-10 col-md-3 col-sm-3 offset-md-0 offset-sm-0">
                        <img src="images/ads.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="ad3">
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- 12 columns on mobile, 7 columns on desktop -->
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-7">
            <!-- video -->
        </div>
        <!-- 12 columns on mobile, 3 columns to the right on desktop -->
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-2 offset-lg-3">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- 
                  3 columns each side by side, which means it takes
                  up 4 columns each. 12 columns on desktop as they
                  need to stack up.
                -->
                <div class="col-4 col-lg-12">ads</div>
                <div class="col-4 col-lg-12">ads</div>
                <div class="col-4 col-lg-12">ads</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/139532/

Comment: Great answer! The only thing that did not work out was the video being aligned in the middle of the jumbotron  while on desktop. I tried to re-add  `justify-content-center` to the `row` but it does not fix it. I think this can be fixed with custom css.

Comment: @Squanchy: what did you mean? On desktop (lg class), the video shouldn't not be in the middle of the jombotron. It should, instead, take up 7 columns (col-lg-7) as what you want in your OP.

Comment: you're totally correct. It was just something that I didn't foresee in my OP, but the answer provided was perfect I fixed the video alignment farely easily with what was given. Thanks again!